# Python pull back plain text body from message from IMAP account

Tags: python, parsing, email, imap, plaintext

I have been working on this and am missing the mark.

I am able to connect and get the mail via imaplib.

```
msrv = imaplib.IMAP4(server)
msrv.login(username,password)

# Get mail

msrv.select()

#msrv.search(None, 'ALL')

typ, data = msrv.search(None, 'ALL')

# iterate through messages
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, msg_itm = msrv.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print msg_itm
    print num
```

But what I need to do is get the body of the message as plain text and I think that works with the email parser but I am having problems getting it working.

Does anyone have a complete example I can look at?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

To get the plain text version of the body of the email I did something like this....

```
xxx= data[0][1] #puts message from list into string


xyz=email.message_from_string(xxx)# converts string to instance of message xyz is an email message so multipart and walk work on it.

#Finds the plain text version of the body of the message.

if xyz.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart': #If message is multi part we only want the text version of the body, this walks the message and gets the body.
    for part in xyz.walk():       
        if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
            body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
        else:
                    continue
```

Comment: and if it isn't `multipart`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal example from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example):

```
import getpass, imaplib

M = imaplib.IMAP4()
M.login(getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass())
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1])
M.close()
M.logout()
```

In this case, data[0][1] contains the message body.

Comment: Thanks. It gave me the message.  Is there any way to get just the body and not the attachments?

Comment: Try this: import email, msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])